# Android Permissions dialog box not coming

Tags: android

I have a phone number activity as well as phone number controller class 
I have defined my checkpermission and requestpermission in my standard methods and calling them from controller class as shown below:

```
public static boolean checkPermission ( Context context ) {
    Log.e ( "checkPermission: " + context.getClass ( ) );
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission (context,
          Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        return true;
    return false;

public static void requestPermission ( Activity activity ) {
        Log.e ( "AA---->>>", "requestPermission: " + activity.getClass ( ) );
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions ( activity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                1);
}


 calling from controller:

boolean isPermissionGiven = StandardMethods.checkPermission ( phoneActivity );
    if ( !isPermissionGiven ) {
       StandardMethods.requestPermission ( phoneActivity );
    }


gives this Error :

E/Utkarsh---: checkPermission: class .PhoneNumberActivity
E/Utkarsh---->>>: requestPermission: class.PhoneNumberActivity
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 80577484
V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 19
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 80577499
E/Utkarsh---: checkPermission: class.PhoneNumberActivity
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 80577732
```

As per logs checkpermission and requestpermission is called

Comment: Do you have `<uses-permission>` elements for both of those permissions in your manifest? Are you running on Android 6.0+? Does your app already have those permissions, as seen in Settings > Apps > (your app) > Permissions?

Comment: if your user has permanently rejected the permissions, the call goes directly to `onActivitResult` in your phoneActivity.

Comment: @CommonsWare this thing runs every time when i havent separated the activity in controller helper and wrote check permission outside the activity .i have wrote everything in uses permission . using marshmallow 6, i saw i have given the permission , now i have taken the permission then request permission method is not only called

Answer (score 0):

The permission i requested were:

```
public static boolean checkPermission ( Context context ) {

if ( hasPermission ( context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ) )
                return true;
else if ( hasPermission ( context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ) )
                return true;
else if ( hasPermission ( context, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS ) )
                return true;
else if ( hasPermission ( context, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS ) )
                return true;
else if ( hasPermission ( context, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS ) )
                return true;
            return false;

}

private static boolean hasPermission ( Context context, String flag ) {
            return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission ( context, flag ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        }
```

There was some problem with **"SEND SMS"** Permission , it always sends permission not granted i dont know why , though i am not sending sms in my app so i removed it . Removing this made my error gone . Before that the error keeps coming infinitely , I dont know why it helped . Though the same permissions works great if written inside activity . Now they are are in non activity class (Standard Methods).

**Please can some one provide the reason**